# Extend 2d polygon by vector

Tags: polygon

I have convex polygons, and I want to extend them by projecting along a vector like so:

[image]

(Original polygon and vector on left, desired result on right.)

My polygons are stored as a series of points with counter-clockwise winding. What I want to find are the "starting" and "stopping" point that I need to project from, as in the circled vertices below.
[image]

(The green arrows are to indicate the polygon's winding, giving the "direction" of each edge.)

My original plan was to determine which points to use by projecting a ray with the vector's direction from each point, and finding the first and last points whose ray doesn't intersect an edge. However, that seems expensive.

Is there a way I can use the edge directions vs the vector direction, or a similar trick, to determine which points to extend from?

Comment: @ChristianHackl My code is in C++, but I decided to use pictures rather than code. I wasn't sure about it either; I will remove it if it is inappropriate.

Comment: IMO it's inappropriate because you are looking for a theoretical solution. That's *good*, because you separate the concept on a piece of paper from its implementation in C++ code. But you should not ask about both things in the same question. The concept is language-independent. You should ask a C++ question only after you have tried to implement it in C++ and have run into problems.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I agree. Tag removed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n.m. [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932222/4647122) the question as I asked and pictured it, but upon programming I soon noticed that there was a common case where all vertices would be "outside" vertices (this can be easily seen on triangles, and can occur for other polygons too).

**The text explanation.**

The solution I used was to look at the normal vectors of the edges leading into and exiting each vertex. The vertices we want to extend are vertices that have at least one edge normal with a minimum angle of less than 90 degrees to the delta vector we are extending by.

The outward-facing edge normals on a counterclockwise-wound polygon can be found by:

`normal = (currentVertex.y - nextVertex.y, nextVertex.x - currentVertex.x)`

Note that since we don't care about the exact angle, we don't need to normalize (make a unit vector of) the normal, which saves a square root.

To compare it to the delta vector, we use the dot product:

`dot = edgeNormal.dot(deltaVector)`

If the result is greater than zero, the minimum angle is acute (less than 90). If the result is exactly zero, the vectors are perpendicular. If the result is less than zero, the minimum angle is obtuse. It is worth noting when the vectors are perpendicular, since it lets us avoid adding extra vertices to the extended polygon.

If you want to visualize how the angle works with the dot product, like I did, just look at a graph of arc cosine (normally you get the angle via acos(dot)).

Now we can find the vertices that have one acute and one not-acute minimum angle between its edge normals and the delta vector. Everything on the "acute side" of these vertices has the delta vector added to it, and everything on the "obtuse side" stays the same. The two boarder vertices themselves are duplicated, having one extended and one staying the same, *unless* the "obtuse side" is exactly perpendicular to the delta vector (in this case we only need to extend the vertex, since otherwise we would have two vertices on the same line).

**Here is the C++ code for this solution.**

It may look a little long, but it is actually quite straightforward and has many comments so it hopefully shouldn't be hard to follow.

It is part of my Polygon class, which has a std::vector of counterclockwise-wound vertices. units::Coordinate are floats, and units::Coordinate2D is a vector class that I feel should be self-explanatory.

```
// Compute the normal of an edge of a polygon with counterclockwise winding, without normalizing it to a unit vector.
inline units::Coordinate2D _get_non_normalized_normal(units::Coordinate2D first, units::Coordinate2D second) {
    return units::Coordinate2D(first.y - second.y, second.x - first.x);
}
enum AngleResult {
    ACUTE,
    PERPENDICULAR,
    OBTUSE
};
// Avoid accumulative floating point errors.
// Choosing a good epsilon is extra important, since we don't normalize our vectors (so it is scale dependent).
const units::Coordinate eps = 0.001;
// Check what kind of angle the minimum angle between two vectors is.
inline AngleResult _check_min_angle(units::Coordinate2D vec1, units::Coordinate2D vec2) {
    const units::Coordinate dot = vec1.dot(vec2);
    if (std::abs(dot) <= eps)
        return PERPENDICULAR;
    if ((dot + eps) > 0)
        return ACUTE;
    return OBTUSE;
}
Polygon Polygon::extend(units::Coordinate2D delta) const {
    if (delta.isZero()) { // Isn't being moved. Just return the current polygon.
        return Polygon(*this);
    }
    const std::size_t numVerts = vertices_.size();
    if (numVerts < 3) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Cannot extend polygon (polygon invalid; must have at least three vertices).\n";
        return Polygon();
    }
    // We are interested in extending from vertices that have at least one edge normal with a minimum angle acute to the delta.
    // With a convex polygon, there will form a single contiguous range of such vertices.
    // The first and last vertex in that range may need to be duplicated, and then the vertices within the range
    // are projected along the delta to form the new polygon.
    // The first and last vertices are defined by the vertices that have only one acute edge normal.

    // Whether the minimum angle of the normal of the edge made from the last and first vertices is acute with delta.
    const AngleResult firstEdge = _check_min_angle(_get_non_normalized_normal(vertices_[numVerts-1], vertices_[0]), delta);
    const bool isFirstEdgeAcute = firstEdge == ACUTE;

    AngleResult prevEdge = firstEdge;
    AngleResult currEdge;
    bool found = false;
    std::size_t vertexInRegion;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numVerts - 1; ++i) {
        currEdge = _check_min_angle(_get_non_normalized_normal(vertices_[i], vertices_[i+1]), delta);
        if (isFirstEdgeAcute != (currEdge == ACUTE)) {
            // Either crossed from inside to outside the region, or vice versa.
            // (One side of the vertex has an edge normal that is acute, the other side obtuse.)
            found = true;
            vertexInRegion = i;
            break;
        }
        prevEdge = currEdge;
    }
    if (!found) {
        // A valid polygon has two points that define where the region starts and ends.
        // If we didn't find one in the loop, the polygon is invalid.
        std::cerr << "Error: Polygon can not be extended (invalid polygon).\n";
        return Polygon();
    }
    found = false;
    std::size_t first, last;
    // If an edge being extended is perpendicular to the delta, there is no need to duplicate that vertex.
    bool shouldDuplicateFirst, shouldDuplicateLast;
    // We found either the first or last vertex for the region.
    if (isFirstEdgeAcute) {
        // It is the last vertex in the region.
        last = vertexInRegion;
        shouldDuplicateLast = currEdge != PERPENDICULAR; // currEdge is either perpendicular or obtuse.
        // Loop backwards from the end to find the first vertex.
        for (std::size_t i = numVerts - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            currEdge = _check_min_angle(_get_non_normalized_normal(vertices_[i-1], vertices_[i]), delta);
            if (currEdge != ACUTE) {
                first = i;
                shouldDuplicateFirst = currEdge != PERPENDICULAR;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Polygon can not be extended (invalid polygon).\n";
            return Polygon();
        }
    } else {
        // It is the first vertex in the region.
        first = vertexInRegion;
        shouldDuplicateFirst = prevEdge != PERPENDICULAR; // prevEdge is either perpendicular or obtuse.
        // Loop forwards from the first vertex to find where it ends.
        for (std::size_t i = vertexInRegion + 1; i < numVerts - 1; ++i) {
            currEdge = _check_min_angle(_get_non_normalized_normal(vertices_[i], vertices_[i+1]), delta);
            if (currEdge != ACUTE) {
                last = i;
                shouldDuplicateLast = currEdge != PERPENDICULAR;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            // The edge normal between the last and first vertex is the only non-acute edge normal.
            last = numVerts - 1;
            shouldDuplicateLast = firstEdge != PERPENDICULAR;
        }
    }

    // Create the new polygon.
    std::vector<units::Coordinate2D> newVertices;
    newVertices.reserve(numVerts + (shouldDuplicateFirst ? 1 : 0) + (shouldDuplicateLast ? 1 : 0) );
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i) {
        // Extend vertices in the region first-to-last inclusive. Duplicate first/last vertices if required.
        if (i == first && shouldDuplicateFirst) {
            newVertices.push_back(vertices_[i]);
            newVertices.push_back(vertices_[i] + delta);
        } else if (i == last && shouldDuplicateLast) {
            newVertices.push_back(vertices_[i] + delta);
            newVertices.push_back(vertices_[i]);
        } else {
            newVertices.push_back( isFirstEdgeAcute ? // Determine which range to use.
                ( (i <= last || i >= first) ? vertices_[i] + delta : vertices_[i] ) : // Range overlaps start/end of the array.
                ( (i <= last && i >= first) ? vertices_[i] + delta : vertices_[i] )); // Range is somewhere in the middle of the array.
        }
    }
    return Polygon(newVertices);
}
```

So far I tested this code with triangles, rectangles, approximated circles, and arbitrary convex polygons made by extending the approximated circles sequentially by many different delta vectors.

Please note that this solution is still only valid for convex polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Look at points where the direction of the vector falls between the directions of the edges.

[image]

In other words, take three vectors:

- of the edge leading out of the vertex
- of the translation vector
- opposite to the edge leading to the vertex

If they are in this order when going CCW, i.e. if the second vector is between the first and the third, this is an "inside" point.

In order to determine whether a vector lies between two other vectors, use cross product as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640931/how-to-determine-if-a-vector-is-between-two-other-vectors).

Comment: This looks much more intuitive to me. I look for all the points that are "outside", correct?

Comment: @Claytorpedo Yes, exactly. The two points you have marked are the leftmost and the rightmost "outside" points. Also you have to deal with the case of the translation vector being exactly parallel to one of the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You want to project along x, y. So the normal is y, -x. Now rotate by that (atan2, or you can you it directly if you understand rotation matrices). The points to project from and now the minimum and maximum x, You can also speed up the projection by always doing it along an axis then rotating back.

Comment: I don't understand. How am I rotating the points with the normal of the vector, and what result am I looking for? Am I doing dot products with the edges and the vector's normal, and looking for a certain result?

Comment: theta = atan2(ny, nx); Then for all the points, rx = x * cos(theta)-y*sin(theta), ry = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta). Now they're rotated, get max and min values, and those are the points you extend as you sweep.

Comment: Thanks. In your answer you mentioned just checking min/max rx. Is calculating ry necessary, and if it is, how does one differentiate min/max in two dimensions?

Comment: We rotate to remove one dimension. We only need to check max/min in x. ry isn't necessary, no.

Comment: Trigonometric functions are unnecessary in this problem.

Comment: I know. I said as much. But the Op's understanding probably isn't up to that yet.