# How can i check if a Vector3 (x,y,z) is between 2 other Vector3's in Java?

Tags: java, position, xyz

I want to make a protection plugin for a Minecraft server software and I want to work with Vector3. I want to check if a Vector3 is between 2 Positions (Vector3).

The Vector3 has got the values: x, y, and z.
How can I check now if a Vector is between 2 others?

```
Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(100, 10, 100);
Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(10, 100, 43);
Vector3 vector3tocheck = new Vector3(60, 23, 1); // it should be between the 2 positions

public boolean isInTwoVectors(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 vector3tocheck) {
// Here idk how to continue.
}
```

I expect the result if it is in the two positions or not.

Comment: What does "between" mean in 3d space?  Coplanar and inside the smaller angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean isInTwoVectors(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 check) {
    int minX = Math.min(pos1.x, pos2.x);
    int maxX = Math.max(pos1.x, pos2.x);
    int minY = Math.min(pos1.y, pos2.y);
    int maxY = Math.max(pos1.y, pos2.y);
    int minZ = Math.min(pos1.z, pos2.z);
    int maxZ = Math.max(pos1.z, pos2.z);
    return check.x >= minX && check.x <= maxX && check.y >= minY && check.y <= maxY
        && check.z >= minZ && check.z <= maxZ;
}
```

Simply, check all the x, y, and z bounds for whether the vector lies within. For the record, in your example, the given vector would not be within the bounds, because its z-value is out of bounds (outside of [43,100]). In this case (not caring about z-value), you'd only check x- and y-values, as so:

```
public boolean isInTwoVectorsXY(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 check) {
    int minX = Math.min(pos1.x, pos2.x);
    int maxX = Math.max(pos1.x, pos2.x);
    int minY = Math.min(pos1.y, pos2.y);
    int maxY = Math.max(pos1.y, pos2.y);
    return check.x >= minX && check.x <= maxX && check.y >= minY && check.y <= maxY;
}
```

Alternatively, maybe you actually mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640931/how-to-determine-if-a-vector-is-between-two-other-vectors) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883075/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-3-dimensional-vector-is-contained-within-the-acute&noredirect=1)?